# Best way to switch between multiple versions of the Flash player for easier testing?

Tags: flash, browser

Are there any utilities or browser plugins that let you easily switch the version of the Flash player that is being used?

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox 3.x on Window XP, Ubutntu Linux, and Mac OS X (Tiger and Leopard), [Flash Switcher](http://www.sephiroth.it/firefox/flash_switcher/) works well.

Comment: Funny, that's the link I pasted before you :p

Comment: note that this won't work with the latest versions of firefox (I tested 11+).  Works great on 3 though.

Answer (score 2):

For a cross-browser, cross-platform solution, you can use this python script:

http://www.mattshaw.org/projects/flash-plugin-switcher/

Answer (score 1):

Found the following: http://www.google.be/search?q=firefox%20switch%20flash%20version

http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2006/10/flash_switcher_for_firefox.php (seems nice)

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=6FBA7 (seems nicely integrated as well)

https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/5044 (from mozilla.org, must be good :p)